# Does using constexpr in array size prevent it from being a VLA?

Tags: arrays, c++11

Does using `constexpr` in array size prevent it from being a VLA? For example:

```
constexpr int buffer_size = 256*2;
char buffer[buffer_size];
```

Is buffer a VLA (variable length array)? How can I tell? I'm using `buffer_size` with `constexpr` int as replacement for macros here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an array can get its size from a `constexpr`.

You can tell by compiling with `-pedantic-errors` on GCC and Clang, which will halt compilation if you accidentally use an extension such as VLAs.

Comment: To be clear: VLA is an extension often used in C, and not part of any C++ standard. Pedantic C++ code on any platform should error if the array size is not a compile-time resolved constant.